# aws ip based routing - Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Is it possible in route53 to configure   point a static ip4 123.12.18.29/32 to a web server.  Aware of geolocation feature exists but cant find where i can configure static ip.  For example can use the geolocation feature in route53 to route all the traffic from singapore to a particular webserver1. Want to route some static ip from singapore to another webserver2.   How can i do it.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't within the capabilities of Route 53, and really, this is not something any DNS hosting service can do, because the client (browser) doesn't usually make the request directly to the authoritative servers.  DNS lookups usually are sent to a recursive DNS resolver, which may be corporate, or owned by the ISP, or a public resolver such as Google's well-known 8.8.8.8.  This system then does the resolution, contacting the Route 53 servers providing either no information at all about the original requester, or providing a somewhat anonymized version of the requesting client's address.

The geolocation documentation of Route 53 is relevant here, because it explains these two options.

> When a browser or other viewer uses a DNS resolver that does not support edns-client-subnet, Amazon Route 53 uses the source IP address of the DNS resolver to approximate the location of the user and responds to geolocation queries with the DNS record for the resolver's location.
>
> When a browser or other viewer uses a DNS resolver that does support edns-client-subnet, the DNS resolver sends Amazon Route 53 a truncated version of the user's IP address. Amazon Route 53 determines the location of the user based on the truncated IP address rather than the source IP address of the DNS resolver; this typically provides a more accurate estimate of the user's location. Amazon Route 53 then responds to geolocation queries with the DNS record for the user's location.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html

**Any desired DNS behavior requiring access to the client's IP address is effectively limited to these two possibilities, regardless of who hosts the DNS.**

These are not limitations of Route 53, but rather of the way DNS works on the global Internet.

DNS resolvers need to be able to cache lookups -- caching is the purpose of TTLs in DNS.  If they sent the client's actual IP address, they would only be able to use the cache entry to respond to the same client address in the future, largely defeating the whole point of caching.

To solve your issue, your servers can either redirect or proxy requests to the alternate destination, but there is no way to return specific DNS responses to specific requesters.